Transponer una tabla
Tengo la siguiente tabla:

Y quiero obtener esta otra tabla:

Lo realizo en dos pasos.
Con esta consulta
SELECT Medida_A, Medida_B, Operacion, Sexo, "E2" AS COD, [E2]  AS Valor
FROM [TABLA1]

UNION ALL
SELECT Medida_A, Medida_B, Operacion, Sexo, "E5" AS COD, [E5] AS Valor
FROM [TABLA1]

UNION ALL SELECT Medida_A, Medida_B, Operacion, Sexo, "E9" AS COD, [E9] AS Valor
FROM [TABLA1];

He obtenido:

Y luego, haciendo

Que en slq sería:
TRANSFORM Sum(Transponer_Ind.Valor) AS SumaDeValor
SELECT Transponer_Ind.Medida_A, Transponer_Ind.Medida_B, Transponer_Ind.Operacion, Transponer_Ind.COD
FROM Transponer_Ind
GROUP BY Transponer_Ind.Medida_A, Transponer_Ind.Medida_B, Transponer_Ind.Operacion, Transponer_Ind.COD
PIVOT Transponer_Ind.Sexo;

obtenemos la tabla que buscamos.
Lo que no consigo es hacerlo en un solo paso.

Eso es access, asi que no tiene de forma nativa el unpivot, dudo mucho que puedas hacerlo de otra forma.
